# Plot.margin fails after scale_y_cut

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to adjust plot margin with the y-axis having a break. However, the `scale_y_cut` seems to interfere with `plot.margin`, since when I ran the following code without `scale_y_cut` the plot margin was adjusted. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
set.seed(5)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggbreak)


data <- data.frame(
  id = c(1:100),
  age = sample(20:80, 100, replace = TRUE),
  sex = sample(c("M", "F"), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3)),
  type = sample(letters[1:5], 100, replace = TRUE),
  name = sample(c("longnamelongnamelongname1", "longnamelongname2longname", "longnamelongnamelongname3", "longnamelongnamelongname4"), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)),
  direction = sample(c("Up", "Down"), 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3)),
  bmi = sample(15:35, 100, replace = TRUE),
  sbp = sample(75:160, 100, replace = TRUE)
 )



ggplot(data, aes(name, age, color=sex, fill=sex, size=sex, shape = type)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  
  # Try with and without this scale_y_cut line of code to see what I meant 
  scale_y_cut(breaks=(c(40)), scale=0.15) +
  
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 3), "cm"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_markdown(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1, size = 10.5), 
        legend.title = element_text(size=12), 
        legend.text = element_text(size=11),
        legend.key.size = unit(.8, "cm"), 
        legend.key.height = unit(.5, "cm"))
```

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with `plot.margin`. The issue is that you set the `breaks` in `scale_y_cut` at a value outside of the plotting range and hence you should get an error message `Some breaks are not in the plot range.` which is what I get when I run your code.

Comment: I replaced 20 with 40 for the `scale_y_cut` breaks, and this problem about margin persisted.

Comment: For me your code works fine with the provided example data using `scale_y_cut(breaks = 40, scale = 0.15)`. But of course do I had to add `library(ggbreaks)`.

Comment: If you run with `scale_y_cut` commented out, and then compare to with this line of code, you will see what I meant. The left margin looks very different.

Comment: Okay. Now I see what you mean. This looks like a bug to me. If no one else comes up with a solution I would suggest to raise an issue on the package Github repo.